# Angular this.object.find is undefined

Tags: angular, function, methods

I need to check each PollDto's result and display on each card this result, with a mat-icon 'clear' if it's wrong and a mat-icon 'done' if it's true.
Currently, my console show me this error :

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'result')
    at ThemeElementComponent.showTheResult (theme-element.component.ts:60:49)
```

And dunno why the part of my showTheResult function is undefined ??
I also tried to load a new value of this.polls in the methode ngOnInit, but nothing better here.

There are my parts of code needed.

```
    <p>{{'CARDIAG.PARCOURS.CARD.DESCRIPTION' | translate}}</p>
    <div class="card" *ngFor="let card of cards">
      <a class="delete-button" (click)="deleteCard.emit(card.id)">+</a>
      <mat-icon *ngIf="showTheResult(card.id)" class="validate__status valid">done</mat-icon>
      <mat-icon *ngIf="!showTheResult(card.id)" class="validate__status refused">clear</mat-icon>
      <app-deck-card [isAnim]="isAnim"
                     [readOnly]="true"
                     [polls]="polls"
                     [card]="card"></app-deck-card>
    </div>
```

The component.ts

```
export class ThemeElementComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() cards: CardDto[];
  @Input() theme: ThemeDto;
  @Input() activities: ActivityDto[];
  @Input() allActivities: ApiActivityDto[];
  @Input() polls: PollDto[];
  @Output() deleteCard = new EventEmitter<number>();
  @Output() deleteActivity = new EventEmitter<number>();
  @Output() deleteTheme = new EventEmitter<void>();

  constructor(private readonly authState: AuthState,
              private dialog: MatDialog,
              private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }

  @Computed() get isAnim(): boolean {
    return this.authState.isAnim[GameEnum.CARDIAG];
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.activities.forEach(activityDto => activityDto.apiActivity = this.allActivities?.find(a => a.id === activityDto.activity));
  }

  sanitize(icon: string): SafeUrl {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(icon);
  }

  showTheResult(cardId: number): boolean {
    return this.polls?.find(p => p.id === cardId).result;
  }
}
```

I tried also this :

```
  showTheResult(cardId: number): boolean {
    return this.polls?.find(p => p.card.id === cardId).result.valueOf();
  }
```

But each card was considered as valid/true :(

The PollDto

```
export interface PollDto {
  id: number;
  result: boolean;
  voted: boolean;
  priority: number;
  card: CardDto;
  votes: VoteDto[];
}
```

Maybe the part with this.polls?.find(.....) is not running like this ?
Thanks

In response of Will, under this post, when i
`console.log(this.polls)` in the function showTheResult, i have a response like this :

```
(22) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
 > card:
   baseCard: false
   dateCreate: "2022-03-09T15:48:06.780+00:00"
   dateUpdate: "2022-03-09T15:48:06.780+00:00"
   id: 1
   priority: null
   text: "Nous faisons… 1 CoDir + 2 CoPil + 4 CoProj avant de prendre des décisions."
   theme: {id: 1, title: 'Decision', color: '#8FBC94', link: 
   'https://www.apitheme.xyz', icon: 
   'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKQA… 
  8v8CARGWuLgOy/N+Rk7XtH9rh7JvT6tVLAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC', …}
  version: 1
  [[Prototype]]: Object
id: 45
priority: 11
result: false
voted: true
votes: []
[[Prototype]]: Object
1:
 > card:
   baseCard: false
   dateCreate: "2022-03-09T15:48:06.780+00:00"
   dateUpdate: "2022-03-09T15:48:06.780+00:00"
   id: 2
   priority: null
   text: "Second Card."
   theme: {id: 1, title: 'Decision', color: '#8FBC94', link: 
   'https://www.apitheme.xyz', icon: 
   'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKQA… 
   8v8CARGWuLgOy/N+Rk7XtH9rh7JvT6tVLAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC', …}
   version: 1
   [[Prototype]]: Object
id: 46
priority: 6
result: false
voted: true
votes: []
....
```

EDIT :
*ngIf seems to does not work in `<mat-icon>`....
I just wrap my icons in `<span *ngIf"...">ICON</span>` or `<div *ngIf="...">ICON</div>` and everything works...

Comment: Your `find` call in `showTheResult` isn't finding anything. Your `polls` Array doesn't contain an element corresponding to your search.

Comment: However my Object polls is not empty. According to you, the method is correct ? the problem concern my Object polls ?

Comment: Your `polls` Array could have 10000 elements in it ^^ none of them has a `card` attribute where the `id` is the same as `cardId`. Be careful of numbers vs. strings, as typing can get messed up sometimes :)

Comment: I just edit the post and shared my console.log(this.polls), i tried to put all numbers into strings, but nothing different from my post...

Comment: Have you used your debugger to make sure that a valid id is being passed?